# How to disable submit button until file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, jquery-validate

I have an HTML file upload page and I need the submit button to be disabled until a file is selected.  Then the submit button will be enabled and the user can upload.  I assume I can use jQuery code to query the file upload field's value to see whether a file has been selected to upload.  And I assume I can check that whenever focus has left the file upload field.  My concern is that some browsers might act funny with this and then my users can't upload any files.

Is there a safe way to do this, preferably using jQuery, where I won't be in danger of having some users unable to upload?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This jQuery should work, and is tied to the file input's [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. This code also *applies* the `disabled` attribute so, in the event the user has JavaScript disabled, it shouldn't prevent the form being used:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()){
                    $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                }
                else {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2Ayu5/).

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Though I'm still a bit scared of browser issues making some users unable to upload, guess I just have to do thorough testing.  It was disabled JavaScript I was worried about, it was JavaScript quirks I was worried about.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way is to check the file field when the user actually submits the form... that way you won't have to look for form changes.

```
$(function() {
   $('form').submit(function() {
      if(!$("form input[type=file]").val()) {
         alert('You must select a file!');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

This code is [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and it won't mess up the form if the user does not support JS.

Comment: This might be "unobtrusive" in the sense of the Wikipedia page but throwing a blocking alert popup in the face of the user is very obtrusive.

Comment: And, to my mind, allowing the user to try and submit the form before the submit conditions are met is, at best, frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

David Thomas's code can be set for button ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=btInsert.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
        $('input:file').change(
            function () {
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('#<%=btInsert.ClientID %>').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=btInsert.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```