# How to enable submit button until condition in a multiple file uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I'm doing a WebApp where people will upload 2 images which I need to pass through a python code. For this reason, I only want to let them send it when 2 images are uploaded.

I've been reading other posts like:

[How to disable submit button until file is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421033/how-to-disable-submit-button-until-file-is-selected)

[Enable submit button after uploading more than 1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214669/enable-submit-button-after-uploading-more-than-1-file)

But I'm not able to extrapolate it to my case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@3.4.3/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.css">
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Uploader -->
<div class="custom-file-container" data-upload-id="myImage">
    <label>Upload your images <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="custom-file-container__image-clear" title="Clear Image">&times;</a></label>

    <label class="custom-file-container__custom-file" >
      <form id="upload-form" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input" accept="image/*" aria-label="Choose File" multiple>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
      <span class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-control"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="custom-file-container__image-preview"></div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="send" disabled/>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@3.4.3/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.js"></script>

<script>
      var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myImage', {showDeleteButtonOnImages: true, text: {chooseFile: 'Nom del fitxer', browse: 'Examina'}})
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);; 
                } 
            }
            );
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The last script added is the solution given in the first link, which works properly but is not what I want.

The file-uploader code is from https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview, where I've seen that there is a method called selectedFilesCount that maybe is useful.

Thank you for your time and sorry if you see some nonsense in my code but I'm new with these languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the `upload.cachedFileArray` from the upload object to check the `array` length to verify if 2 files have been selected for upload. This is checked via a toggle() function that is bound by the `window event listeners` `fileUploadWithPreview:imageSelected` and `fileUploadWithPreview:imageDelete`, so if an image is removed after being selected, you can still enforce the rule of 2:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});

var toggle = function() {
  //console.log(upload.cachedFileArray.length);
  if (upload.cachedFileArray.length == 2) {
    $('input:submit').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
};

window.addEventListener('fileUploadWithPreview:imageSelected', function(e) {
  // optionally you could pass the length into the toggle function as a param
  // console.log(e.detail.cachedFileArray.length);
  toggle();
});

window.addEventListener('fileUploadWithPreview:imageDeleted', function(e) {
  // optionally you could pass the length into the toggle function as a param
  // console.log(e.detail.cachedFileArray.length);
  toggle();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@3.4.3/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Uploader -->
  <div class="custom-file-container" data-upload-id="myImage">
    <label>Upload your images <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="custom-file-container__image-clear" title="Clear Image">&times;</a></label>

    <label class="custom-file-container__custom-file">
      <form id="upload-form" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input" accept="image/*" aria-label="Choose File" multiple>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
      <span class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-control"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="custom-file-container__image-preview"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="send" disabled/>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/file-upload-with-preview@3.4.3/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myImage', {
      showDeleteButtonOnImages: true,
      text: {
        chooseFile: 'Nom del fitxer',
        browse: 'Examina'
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the answer to better handle if a file is removed after being selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works as I want, the only change needed is to include the following part because when I uploaded 3 files the submit button was still enable:     
           else {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                }

Comment: Yup, I updated my answer. Please see updated snippet. Please mark as accepted answer if this suits what you were looking for.Thanks!

Comment: I've post the comment before your edits. With the new upload it works perfect! The fact of uploading more than 2 files and then remove some of them is an error that I didn't think about and I've seen that it would be a problem!!! Thanks for your attention @Woodrow!

Comment: You're most welcome! I realized after I posted the original snippet that it could be an issue if someone removed a file, so I just wanted to make sure I covered the bases. Glad I could help!